# Determine if a Shape is within a Table using Index based Reference

Tags: vba, ms-word

To determine if a Shape is within a `Table` you can use the following code:

```
 ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(1).Select

 If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
      MsgBox "In Table"
 Else
      MsgBox "Not In Table"
 End If
```

I am trying to remove all the `Select` / `Selection` etc from my code and moving to index based referencing, which I can then use the Referenced shape to perform various changes. But i can't seem to figure out how to determine if it is in a Table.

I need something like:

```
 Dim CurrentPicture As InlineShape
 Set CurrentPicture = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(1)

 If CurrentPicture.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
      MsgBox "In Table"
 Else
      MsgBox "Not In Table"
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
 CurrentPicture.Range.Information(wdWithInTable)
```